# Function's default value not shared among calls

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python. While going over the official introduction https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html, I couldn't quite understand the last example in section in 4.7.1. Specifically, why does

```
def f(a, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

not share values among subsequent calls when the function is evaluated without explicitly providing the default value for `L`?

Suppose I evaluate `f(1)` and `f(2)` in succession. For the first call, `L` is set to `None`, the default value, so the `if` loop condition is satisfied and `L` is set to `[]`. `L` is then modified to `[1]` and returned as output. On the second call, `L` is still `[1]` *, which is not `None`, so the `if` loop should not be initiated, and I would expect the output to simply be `2` appended to `[1]`, i.e. `[1,2]`, whereas the output is `[2]`.

So * must be false. But when I evaluate `print(f(1))`, I get `[1]` as output, not `None`. Compounding to my confusion is the penultimate example in the same section:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L

print f(1)
print f(2)
print f(3)
```

returns

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

What is going on over here? The website does say default values are only evaluated once, so does the value only carry over when the default value is set to a mutable object, as is the case above with `[]`? If that is so, I would presume `None` is immutable in the first example, and the value of `L` that is returned is discarded immediately upon execution and display of the output.

Comment: You missed the point of "default values are only evaluated once". The default value is defined during compile time, not while the script runs.

Comment: @Matthias Then why does the function defined in the second example accumulate arguments passed to it on subsequent calls?

Comment: *"On the second call, `L` is still `[1]`"* – It's not. It starts out as `None` again and is initialised to `[]` again. It's a local variable, it doesn't keep state beyond one function call.

Comment: @SystematicDisintegration: In the second example you define a list as the default value. The list itself will not change (same id), but the content of the list is altered.

Comment: @deceze In that case, like I asked before, why do the arguments of the second function accumulate on successive calls? If L is indeed a local variable, all previous calls should be irrelevant - upon arbitrary execution without a specified second argument, `L` should be set to `[]`.

Comment: You mean *of the __second__ function*? See the duplicate then, it's well explained there.